# How to define Windows driver name?

Tags: windows, driver, inf

I am trying to define the name of my driver as it appears when it is being installed as flagged by UAC.

Here is an image of the issue:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to change the name of this parameter, and I do not know where it is coming from. I want the name to read 'Argon R1 Mainboard'.

Here are the relevant details from the inf:

```
[Version] 
Signature = "$Windows NT$" 
Class=USB
ClassGUID={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} 
Provider=%LoveElectronics%
CatalogFile.NTx86   = Argonx86.cat
CatalogFile.NTIA64  = Argoia64.cat
CatalogFile.NTAMD64 = Argamd64.cat

[Strings] 
ClassName           = ".NET Micro Framework"
USB\Vid_16D0&Pid_06F4.DeviceDesc = "Argon R1 Mainboard"
LoveElectronics     = "Love Electronics Ltd"

VERSION             = "1.2"
INQUIRIES_INTERFACE = "{265820CE-19E5-4530-8861-262E97E78575}"
SourceDesc          ="driver installation media"
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487309.aspx

Comment: So the Name is not for the product name, it is for the device type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name comes from the .inf file. You can set it with the DriverPackageDisplayName entry in the Version section, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547502.aspx

The following will display "Your Driver Display Name" as the name in the UAC prompt:

```
[Version]
DriverPackageDisplayName = %DisplayName%

[Strings] 
DisplayName = "Your Driver Display Name"
```

If DriverPackageDisplayName is not set then Windows will combine the Provider and Class entires from the Version section to get a display name, as you can see in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that UAC prompts come from the digital signature on the binary, not the INF file.  What parameters are you using to sign the binary, and how are you setting properties on the .SYS file?